# TreeView node only works one time

Tags: c#, treeview

I have this treeview menu [image]

with this code :

```
TreeNode treeNode4 = new TreeNode("Importação CT-I", array5);
treeView1.Nodes.Add(treeNode4);

TreeNode nodeusu1 = new TreeNode("Usuários");
TreeNode nodeusu2 = new TreeNode("Servers");
TreeNode nodeusu3 = new TreeNode("Permissões");
TreeNode nodeusu4 = new TreeNode("Alterar Senha");
TreeNode nodeusu5 = new TreeNode("Sobre");
TreeNode nodeusu6 = new TreeNode("Encerrar");
TreeNode[] array6 = new TreeNode[] { nodeusu1, nodeusu2, nodeusu3, nodeusu4, nodeusu5, nodeusu6 };


private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    if (treeView1.SelectedNode.Text == "Grupo")
    {
        frm_grupo grupo = new frm_grupo();
        grupo.TopLevel = false;
        grupo.AutoScroll = true;
        panelmain.Controls.Add(grupo);
        grupo.Show();
    }

    else if (treeView1.SelectedNode.Text == "Servers")
    {
        Conecta Servidor = new Conecta();
        Servidor.TopLevel = false; 
        Servidor.AutoScroll = true;
        panelmain.Controls.Add(Servidor);
        Servidor.Show();
            Servidor.BringToFront();
    }
}
```

All the nodes works fine but the node "Servers" works only one time, if I change to another  node, the node "Servers" don't work again, what am I doing wrong?

Conecta is a Windows Form with the same Namespace of the form. Hans but where i put the dispose()??? I have added brintofront() is working but where i put the dispose() to close the last

Comment: What is the Type of Conecta?

Comment: Place a breakpoint on the `else if(... == "Servers")` -- do you reach this breakpoint on the second attempt?  If yes, what is the value of `treeView1.SelectedNode.Text` at that moment?

Comment: You keep adding controls but you don't remove the old ones.  An added one will appear *underneath* an old one.  It's there but you just won't see it if it isn't big enough.  You should either keep track of the ones you already added and use BringToFront on the one you want to select or you'll need to Dispose() the old one.

Comment: What is that "won't work"?

Comment: Just an off-topic advice: don't write source code in your mother tongue unless it is English. Conecta, Servidor, I can guess these more or less, but it can get wild after sometime. I also don't write source code in Hungarian for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to understand what you're trying to do here (and the Spanish doesn't help) so please correct me if I'm getting this wrong:

You want to pop up a new Form whenever the user selects the "Servers" tag.

It looks like your code is fine, and you don't want to call "Dispose" or your form will disappear.  What you need to do is to make Servidor an instance object so that you can keep track of it.  Instantiate it, then register for it's Closed event to know that user closed it so that you can either create a new instance or popup the previous instance again.  You also don't need to make it part of the main form's control library.  If you want it to be a child form (like a modal), then pass the main form reference (this) as a parameter in the "Show" method.

```
TreeNode treeNode4 = new TreeNode("Importação CT-I", array5);
treeView1.Nodes.Add(treeNode4);

TreeNode nodeusu1 = new TreeNode("Usuários");
TreeNode nodeusu2 = new TreeNode("Servers");
TreeNode nodeusu3 = new TreeNode("Permissões");
TreeNode nodeusu4 = new TreeNode("Alterar Senha");
TreeNode nodeusu5 = new TreeNode("Sobre");
TreeNode nodeusu6 = new TreeNode("Encerrar");
TreeNode[] array6 = new TreeNode[] { nodeusu1, nodeusu2, nodeusu3, nodeusu4, nodeusu5, nodeusu6 };

Conecta Servidor = null;


private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    if (treeView1.SelectedNode.Text == "Grupo")
    {
        frm_grupo grupo = new frm_grupo();
        grupo.TopLevel = false;
        grupo.AutoScroll = true;
        panelmain.Controls.Add(grupo);
        grupo.Show();
    }

    else if (treeView1.SelectedNode.Text == "Servers")
    {
        if(Servidor == null)
        {
            Servidor = new Conecta();
            Servidor.TopLevel = false; 
            Servidor.AutoScroll = true;
            Servidor.Closed += new FormClosedEventHandler(ServidorClosed);
        }
        Servidor.Show();
            Servidor.BringToFront();
    }
}
private void ServidorClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Servidor != null)
        Servidor.Dispose();
    Servidor == null;
}
```